# Как в консольном приложении выводить "приглашение" в виде символа?

Tags: java, io

Если выполнить такой код:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please, enter your key-word");
String str = sc.nextLine();
```

То после фразы будет пустая строка, ожидающая ввод данных. Как сделать чтобы выводился символ приглашения в этой строке и после него уже можно было вводить данные. Например так:

```
Please, enter your key-word
>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter string");

String str = "";

do {
    System.out.print("> ");
    str = scanner.nextLine();
} while(str.equals(""));
```

В итоге при вводе пустой строки опять выводится приглашающий символ:

```
Enter string
> 
> 
> 
> 
> hello

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: то что надо, спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Предлагаю такой вариант:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Please, enter your key-word\n> ");
String str = sc.nextLine();
```

`System.out.print(...)` в отличии от `System.out.println(...)` не добавляет в конец строки символ перевода строки.